# Linq Grouping Order By Date then Time

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Good Evening,

I've managed to get my Linq query almost correct. There is just one more issue I'm struggling to resolve.

My query is

```
var o =
  (from c in x
   group c by x.Date.Date into cc
   select new 
   { 
      Group = cc.Key.Date, 
      Items = cc.ToList(),
      ItemCount = cc.Count() 
   }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Group);
```

Now this query works fine. It groups within a ListView by the date. x.Date is a DateTime field in my SQL Database. Therefore I'm selecting x.Date.Date to Group by the actual Date of the DateTime field, as if it was just x.Date it would Group by the date and time.

My question is, how do I group by time so the newest time is at the top of the group?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Items = cc.ToList()` to `Items = cc.OrderBy(c => c.[field_you_want_to_sort_by]).ToList()`

Answer (score 4):

Use the linq "ThenBy()" method:

```
var o = (from c in x group c by x.Date.Date into cc select new 
  { 
    Group = cc.Key.Date, 
    Items = cc.OrderByDescending(y=>y.Date).ToList(), 
    ItemCount = cc.Count() 
  })
  .OrderByDescending(p => p.Group)
```

Comment: The only options I can select in ThenBy would be p.Group, p.Items and p.ItemCount

Comment: Edited; the Items property can be sorted when created. Then, you order the groups. So, the groups, keyed by day, are sorted in descending order, and then the items within the groups are sorted in descending order of date *and* time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var o =
  (from c in x
   group c by c.Date.Date into cc
   select new 
   { 
      Group = cc.Key.Date, 
      Items = cc.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Date.Time).ToList(),
      ItemCount = cc.Count() 
   }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Group);
```